# Printing J Largest integers from unsorted list in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, new-operator

I'm trying to write a function that prints the K largest integers from an array of unsorted values.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

void printKLargest(int array[], int k, int size);

int main() {
    int array[5] = {1, 100, 2, 500, 6};
    int k = 2;
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    findKLargest(array, k, size);

}

void printKLargest(int array[], int k, int size) {
    int *largest = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] > largest[0]) {
            largest[0] = array[i];
            for (int j = 1; j < k && largest[j-1] > largest[j]; j++) {
                int t = largest[j]; largest[j] = largest[j-1]; largest[j-1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        std::cout << largest[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

The code above only prints the first integer from `largest` correctly.  In C I was able to get it working correctly using malloc, but using new in C++ is throwing me off a bit.  Thank you.

edit - if I change the line `int *largest = new int[k]` to `int *largest = (int *)malloc(sizeof(k));` I get the desired value. Can somebody explain why this is the case?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.

Comment: If this isn't for academia, I'd suggest using [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element).

Comment: @NathanOliver You might notice that's even a reasoning to close a question. Not debugged code thrown here and saying find the error for me is off-topic. Otherwise I well appreciate your good  workings on StackOverflow!

Comment: What do you mean by [only prints the first integer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85369fd592567f23) ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for that.  Idk why I didn't vtc. I have now

Comment: @NathanOliver `but using new in C++ is throwing me off a bit.`.  The function leaks memory.  Prefer `std::vector<int> largest(k)` instead of `new [ ]`

Answer (score 2):

At least the allocated elements pointed to by largest were not initialized

```
int *largest = new int[k];
```

Thus the program has undefined behaviour.

Also after the assignment

```
if (array[i] > largest[0]) {
   largest[0] = array[i];
```

you lost the value of `largest[0]` that could be copied in `largest[1]`.

The assignment can be done simply if to use standard algorithm `std::partial_sort_copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

//...

void printKLargest( const int array[], size_t n, size_t k ) 
{
    if ( n < k ) k = n;

    std::vector<int> largest( k );

    std::partial_sort_copy( array, array + n, 
                            largest.begin(), largest.end(),
                            std::greater<int>() );

    for ( int x : largest ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

void printKLargest( const int array[], size_t n, size_t k ) 
{
    if ( n < k ) k = n;

    std::vector<int> largest( k );

    std::partial_sort_copy( array, array + n, 
                            largest.begin(), largest.end(),
                            std::greater<int>() );

    for ( int x : largest ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 5, 3, 7, 6, 3, 9, 0 };
    printKLargest( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), 2 );
}
```

The program output is

```
9 7
```

Instead of the vector you may use a dynamically allocated array but you should not forget to delete it.